# Show that $(\lambda - a)(\lambda - d) - bc$ is equivalent to $(a - \lambda)(d - \lambda) - (-b)(-c)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The title says it all: how can I show that $(\lambda - a)(\lambda - d) - bc$ is equivalent to $(a - \lambda)(d - \lambda) - (-b)(-c)$? An answer has been made that correctly does what I want. However, how would you then rewrite both expressions to $\lambda^2 - \lambda(a+d)+(ad-bc)$ because apparently that is also possible?

Comment: Use that $$(-b)(-c)=(-1)^2bc$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner ah, but how would you then rewrite both expressions to $\lambda^2 - \lambda(a+d)+(ad-bc)$? Because apparently that should also be possible.

Comment: Expanding $$(\lambda-a)(\lambda-b)-bc$$ gives $$\lambda^2-a\lambda-b\lambda+ab-bc$$

Comment: using the law $$(a+b)(c+d)=ac+bc+ad+bd$$

Comment: Yea of course! Thanks!!!

Comment: I hope you could solve your problem now?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply multiplying each term by $-1$; multiplying $-1$ twice simply is multiplying $1$ which does not affect the expression.